# Frame-mounted basket options

Tags: cargo, basket

Team,

I recently acquired a Yuba Mundo cargo bike, which is wonderful, but I would like a little more storage room when I have passengers on the load space in back. It has these two mounting points for a front basket on the downtube and top tube.

[image: yuba mundo basket mounting points]

Yuba sells a basket designed to work with this system, but I'm not entirely keen on it. Is this a standard system that other manufacturers make baskets for, or is this a Yuba proprietary system?

Comment: By "passengers", I hope you mean a child on a properly fitted child seat. Rear racks aren't to be used to carry any other kind of passenger.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - this is a cargo bike. Yuba advertises (and presumably engineers) their bikes as being able to take adults on the rear rack.

Comment: Anyway, I think you're stuck with the Yuba proprietary system (not sure, so not writing an answer).

Comment: How about  @DavidRicherby "good thinking, I totally agree and would never carry riders on the parcel rack of a normal bike.  Fortunately its not an issue because this is a cargo bike and I can carry two children in the load bin with seatbelts and padded cushions.  The photo was zoomed in to show the downtube/top tube mounts rather than the whole bike."     
SE comments are ephemeral, to try and help the question improve or be clarified.  I'll edit the question now, and you should see a notification.  Feel free to roll it back or improve the edit if the sense is changed.

Comment: It would certainly be possible to make an adaptor to fit another basket. But that depends on your skill and tools, or alternatively your budget.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's a proprietary system.

That said, front racks and baskets that mount to the head tube are very stable. The rack basket doesn't flop around when parked and it doesn't affect steering when you're riding. Unfortunately there aren't standard head tube mounts (Brompton has one design for example). Until a standard emerges, this is the best we can do with. The only downside aside from the price is that you can't easily hang large front side panniers because they would interfere with steering.

Most off the shelf front baskets and pannier racks mount either to the handlebars or to the pannier mounts on the front fork and suffer from said mentioned floppiness.

Tldr: it's proprietary but worth shelling out for.